# How to integrate okta in ASP.NET Core6 web App(MVC)

Tags: .net, okta, asp.net-core-6.0

How to integrate okta  in ASP.NET Core6 web App(MVC).

below code i have tried it is not working. "!HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated " is not able identifying intellisense

Answer (score 0):

We're still in the process of updating our samples to show .NET 6 specifically, however, the code shown in our core 3 sample is still valid and provides a basic example of Okta integration with .NET MVC.

https://github.com/okta/samples-aspnetcore/blob/master/samples-aspnetcore-3x/okta-hosted-login/okta-aspnetcore-mvc-example/Startup.cs

Comment: !HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated. code is used in Dotnetcore3. please share supported code for DotnetCore6

Comment: 6 months and still no docs on using core 6?  It does not map 1:1 straight across as many things are different.

Comment: Agreed @KeithBarrows. I followed the reference tutorial on Okta dev documentation, and I am still having trouble getting the code I downloaded from their official repo to run on my machine. It is unfortunate that the docs are so outdated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how complete they are, but there do now appear to be samples for more recent versions of ASP.NET Core.

[image]

https://github.com/okta/samples-aspnetcore